# Complex residue theorem integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How would I apply the residue theorem to work out the following integral?
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2\theta\, d\theta}{5-4\cos\theta}
\end{equation}
I've looked into the residue theorem but I can't figure how to do this question properly
Applying known relations I got to:

\begin{equation}
\oint-\frac{\frac{(z-\frac{1}{z})^2}{4}}{5-2(z+\frac{1}{z})}
\end{equation}

Which I then simplified to
\begin{equation}
\oint-\frac{z^3-1}{4z^2(-2(z+\frac{1}{z})+5)}
\end{equation}

I'm now unsure where to go with this, I have the residue theorem written in front of me but I'm struggling to understand from the notes I have what I need to do next in this situation

Comment: Do you want to use the residue theorem or would you prefer a different method?

Comment: Could you show us an attempt that gets an incorrect answer? You'll learn a lot from us pointing out an error.

Comment: Yes, the question requires use of the residue theorem

Comment: @GroupTheory14 you can contribute to the forum by uploading your own answer, I would very much like to see it.

Comment: Further to @AnindyaPrithvi, [we encourage answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). You can even [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) after a while.

Comment: I went away and used an Integral calculator and found I was way off, I've started again from the start, can you tell me if I've made a mistake in my substitution or what I could do next? @J.G

Comment: Your $z^3$ should be $z^2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

By defining $z=e^{i\theta}$, substitute
$$
\cos \theta={z+z^{-1}\over 2}
\\
\sin \theta={z-z^{-1}\over 2i}
$$with $dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta=izd\theta$ the contour being $|z|=1$.